# Do I need to sign my assemblies for an asp.net mvc app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, assembly-signing

If I'm deploying an asp.net mvc app, do I need to sign my DLLs?  They won't be placed in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

No, but Microsoft do recommend signing every assembly as is it well-recongised as good practice (you may want to deploy to the GAC in the future).